# Zf2 float validation is invalid but validator messages are empty

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

I have been doing some search and research and I haven't been able to find why the following is happening:

When the code below is executed the isValid method returns false but the getMessages methods returns an empty array. Does anyone know why?

```
$floatValidator = new Float(array('locale' => 'en_US'));
$floatValidator->isValid('4,9');
$floatValidator->getMessages();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is official reported in ZF2. You can check status:

https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6647